# Visual Studio Code LiveShare "This Operation is not allowed for non-owners"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to share something over vscode liveshare it doesn't let me, stating that "This Operation is not allowed for non-owners"

I made the file myself using the touch command in gitbash so I don't know how I'm not the owner, or who the owner is.

[image: Here is the issue]

I tried to login to various accounts to see which one it thought was the owner, but the same issue happened regardless of if I was signed into my microsoft or github account on vscode.

Comment: Managed to fix this, turns out that when I went to go check who owned the files by checking the drives, turns out I wasn't the owner. After changing all the files to be owned by me it worked just fine.